# React Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$2f71vks24hx' of null

Tags: reactjs

While importing images, I'm getting a warning:

`Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$2f71vks24hx' of null`.

Can someone please let me know why this is happening?

```
import img_logo from '../../../../images/logo/logo.png';
<img src={img_logo} alt="logo" className="brand-logo"/>

import Images from '../components/images/images';
const Image = Images.icons.map((icon, index) => {
  return(
    <div key={index} className="technology-container">
      <p className="technology-title">{icon.title}</p>
      <img src={icon.path} alt={icon.title} className="technology-icon"/>
    </div> 
  );
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @AanchalSharma.. You're right. I had a duplication of react component. I have figured it out solve my problem. Thank you so much..